# Formula for find and replace

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet that in column `A1`, could have "IP5521", or "IP5531", or "IP5621", or "SIP", I would like if I see "IPXXXX", I put in `B1` "IPT", if I see "SIP", I put "SIP" in `B1`.

The function below works but I need wild card for the 5522, because that could change depending on the phone

```
=IF(J4="IP5522","IPT",IF(J4="SIP","SIP",""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(LEFT(J4,2)="IP","IPT",IF(J4="SIP",J4,""))`